# HttpWebRequest using Saml2SecurityToken

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a Saml2Security token provided from ThinkTecture Identity Server but i cannot for the life of me figure out how to use this token when making a HttpWebRequest from the server side.

Can Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

When I think of a samltoken I generally think of it as being generated on the identity server side and then that does a http post to the relying party.  After the post The IClaimsPrinciple (with wif and .net) is populated and the relying party server will have all the claims for the user.  From there you can persist them in a cookie using a jsonwebtoken or in another manner.  Where is the relying party server trying to make a webrequest to, or if you are talking about the javascript client has the saml token then it might be easier to use a simple web token or json web token with a symetric key rather than samltoken.